# Separar plantilla html para agregar contenido dinámico entre etiquetas. Angular 6+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

## Contexto

Estoy tratando de hacer este html dinámico.:

```
    <!-- 
=====================================
 HEADERS
=====================================
-->

<div class="modal fade" [id]="idModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class=" modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div *ngIf="detalleElemento" class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Clave: <strong>{{detalleElemento?.clave}}</strong></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">




                    <!-- 
=====================================
 END HEADERS
=====================================
-->

                    <!-- 
=====================================
 Body
=====================================
-->


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <strong>Nombre de la maquina </strong>
                            <h1> {{detalleElemento.nombre}}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-6">
                            Anio: <strong>{{detalleElemento.anio}} </strong> | Serie: <strong> {{detalleElemento.numeroDeSerie}}</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h3>Departamentos</h3>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li *ngFor="let depto of detalleElemento.departamentos" class="list-group-item">{{depto.nombre}}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h3>Nombres anteriores</h3>
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li *ngFor="let nombre of detalleElemento.nombresAnteriores" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-lg-center ">
                                    <span>
                                        {{nombre.nombre}} \ {{ nombre.clave }}

                                    </span>
                                    <strong class="text-muted"><small>{{nombre.fechaDeCambio | fecha }}</small></strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h3>Observaciones</h3>
                            <p>{{detalleElemento.observaciones}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- 
=====================================
 END Body
=====================================
-->

                    <!-- 
=====================================
 Footer
=====================================
-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- 
=====================================
 END Footer
=====================================
-->
```

Quiero mantener el header y el footer estáticos y modificar de manera dinámica el body.

## El problema

Al tratar de crear un componente header y uno footer necesito cerrar las etiquetas, pero para este fin no me funciona(El html final se descompondrá). Como se puede solucionar este problema? Trabaje un poco con thymeleaf de java y podía crear una sección del código sin problemas, pero en angular esto no se puede hacer o no encontrado como hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar.

### Actualización.

Al parecer no se puede trabajar de esta manera en angular. Será necesario algún componente extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo haber entendido bien tu problema, y la solución sería, en mi opinión la mejor, la siguiente:

Crea un componente, llamemosle `BootstrapModal`. Este componente tendrá un header y footer estaticos y pintara el body que tú reflejes.

```html
 <div class="modal fade" [id]="idModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"> 
    <div class=" modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div *ngIf="detalleElemento" class="modal-content"> 
                 <div class="modal-header"> 
                       <h5 class="modal-title">Clave:                                                <strong>{{detalleElemento?.clave}}</strong>
                       </h5> 
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
                       </button>
                </div>
         <div class="modal-body"> <div class="container-fluid">

          <ng-content></ng-content>


            </div> 
       </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Eso sería el template de tu componente `BootstrapModal`. Fíjate en la etiqueta `ng-content`. Esa etiqueta sirve para 'reflejar' contenido.

Ahora, solo tendrías que pintar tu componente y pasarle el body que quieras de la siguiente manera:.

```html
<bootstrap-modal>
<div class="row"> <div class="col-12"> <strong>Nombre de la maquina </strong> <h1> {{detalleElemento.nombre}}</h1> </div> </div> <div class="row"> <div class="col-6"> Anio: <strong>{{detalleElemento.anio}} </strong> | Serie: <strong> {{detalleElemento.numeroDeSerie}}</strong> </div> </div> <hr> <div class="row"> <div class="col-12"> <h3>Departamentos</h3> <ul class="list-group"> <li *ngFor="let depto of detalleElemento.departamentos" class="list-group-item">{{depto.nombre}}</li> </ul> </div> </div> <div class="row mt-5"> <div class="col-12"> <h3>Nombres anteriores</h3> <ul class="list-group"> <li *ngFor="let nombre of detalleElemento.nombresAnteriores" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-lg-center "> <span> {{nombre.nombre}} \ {{ nombre.clave }} </span> <strong class="text-muted"><small>{{nombre.fechaDeCambio | fecha }}</small></strong> </li> </ul> </div> </div> <div class="row mt-5"> <div class="col-12"> <h3>Observaciones</h3> <p>{{detalleElemento.observaciones}}</p> </div> </div>  
</bootstrap-modal>
```

Para entendernos, `ng-content` te brinda la posibilidad de insertar en tus componente otros componente. Espero haber sido claro y te sirva

(Perdón por el formateo pero desde el móvil es difícil)

Comment: Exactamente lo que ocupaba.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como lo tienes nada te impide crear un nuevo componente para el "body", ponerlo en medio y llamarlo desde el componente externo, con el valor de detalleElemento:

```
<!-- externo.component.html -->
<!-- Headers... (tu código HTML) -->
<app-body [detalleElemento]="detalleElemento"></app-body>
<!-- Footer... (tu código HTML) -->
```

Así al menos conseguirías una mejor organización del código.

Yo en particular siempre intento que tanto header como footer sean independientes y no dejen divs abiertos, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<app-header></app-header>
<app-body></app-body>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

```
<!-- header.component.html -->
<nav class="navbar">
  <!-- ... -->
</nav>
```

```
<!-- body.component.html -->
<main role="main">
  <!-- ... -->
</main>
```

```
<!-- footer.component.html -->
<footer class="footer">
  <!-- ... -->
</footer>
```

Comment: En este caso no lo puedo hacer así por qué es un modal de boostrap. Y el body es el que quiero que cambié. Cada detalle tiene diferente estructura HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien lo que buscas es aplicar el patrón de diseño [Composite View](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/pattern.html), muy famoso en `java` por el framework [Apache tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/index.html).

En angular se puede aplicar una lógica similar con el template `ng-transclude` como muestra el siguiente código:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <div>{{ name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container" ng-transclude>
        <!-- display other boxes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

El código completo lo puedes ver [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723933/angularjs-composite-view-with-the-same-directive/17741610). Aunque en la [documentación de angular de ng-transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) viene el ejemplo con header, body y footer (En concreto el que dice `Multi-slot transclusion`) que me parece se asemeja mas a lo que deseas.

Comment: Gracias por la informacion pero en este caso la Ilsanchez se acopla mejor a mis necesidades. `ng-trasnclude` toma una porción del html existente en la página y lo llama desde donde se necesite. `ng-content` me permite insertar todo el contenido de otro componente y ponerlo en medio de otro sin perder la relación con el componente detalle.

Answer (score -1):

Crea dos componentes uno para el header y otro para el footer, recuerda usar las etiquetas `<header> y <footer>` en cada componentes.
Para crear tu componenente, utiliza el cli de angular, solo de bes tipear:

```
ng generate component header
```

o puedes usar también

```
ng g c header
```

y para usar ese componente simplemente lo llamas de la siguiente forma donde lo vayas a usar.

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

Comment: Angular no compila porque detecta un error en las etiquetas. De esa manera no funciona.

Comment: Tienes un problema en la estructura en tu HTML, chequea si cerrastes todas las etiquetas

Comment: Ocupo no cerrar las etiquetas. Si te das cuenta es un modal de boostrap y el contenido dentro del modal es lo que quiero que cambie.